# LINQ generate serial number

Tags: c#, linq

I joined two datatables & trying to get the results in the array with a serial number. 
dt

```
ID   A    B    C
1    ab   t    j
2    cd   h    k
3    ds   f    g
```

ndt

```
CID     E    F   G
1       g    y   gg
2       ff   hg  vcb
3       df   vb   b
```

Code

```
var query = from r0w1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
            join r0w2 in ndt.AsEnumerable()
            on r0w1.Field<string>("ID") equals r0w2.Field<string>("CID")
            select r0w2.ItemArray.Skip(1).Concat(r0w1.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

What I want here is that the linq should also generate serial number. So, the output should like this.

```
SNO     ID   A    B    C     E    F   G
1       1    ab   t    j     g    y   gg
2       2    cd   h    k     ff   hg  vcb
3       3    ds   f    g     df   vb   b
4...
```

How can I get the serial number here ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing some weird things here, but anyway, this should work:

```
int serialNumber = 1;

var query = from r0w1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
            join r0w2 in ndt.AsEnumerable()
            on r0w1.Field<string>("ID") equals r0w2.Field<string>("CID")
            select new string [] { serialNumber++.ToString() }
                   .Concat(r0w2.ItemArray.Skip(1))
                   .Concat(r0w1.ItemArray).ToArray();
```